# JAVA accessing items inside an object array

Tags: java, object

so I have got a class that has the following method signature

```
public void doStuff(**Object[] lists**)
{ 
    ...
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to access the individual elements in the **lists**

For example, if one of the objects passed (say `list[0]`) is a Character array (`Character[] = {'a', 'd', 'z'}`) then how would I find out from this method that `lists[0]` has 'a' 'd' and 'z' in it?

I have tried code like: `Object list0 = list[0];` but then I am absolutely lost on how to get the *contents* of **list[0]** (in this case, 'a' 'd' and 'z').

Any ideas?

(UPDATE)

Thanks for the responses.  I was able to modify your guys' ideas and make it work :)

Comment: If you know you have arrays in the `lists`, you can cast the elements. For example, `((Character[])lists[0])[0]`

Comment: If you have an array of arrays, you could use multidimensional arrays (lists[][])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drill down the param as required:

```
public void doStuff(Object[] lists) 
{ 
   Object entry0 = lists[0]; //Object Array only contains objects.
   char[] charArr = (char[]) entry0; // Explicit cast: You know that lists[0] is a char Array!
   for (char c : charArr)
   {
     System.out.println("Char Array contains: " + c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays have strings: (otherwise replace whatever object you are using)

```
Object first = lists[0];
ArrayList<String> individual = (ArrayList<String>)first;
String itemOne = individual.get(0);
```